# how to get last 6 week start date and end date in MSSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

For Example, today is **18 Feb 2021** then the start date will be 14 Feb 2021 and the End Date will be 20 Feb 2021.

These ways for the last 3 weeks will be :

| week | start date | End Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Week 1 | 14 Feb 2021 | 20 Feb 2021 |
| week 2 | 7 Feb 2021 | 13 Feb 2021 |
| week 3 | 31 Jan 2021 | 6 Feb 2021 |

Here week 1 is the current week, week 2 is the week before week 1 so on

I have tried the below script :

```
select cast(DATEADD(dd, -(DATEPART(dw, getdate())-1), getdate()) as date) [Week1 start]

select cast(DATEADD(dd, 7-(DATEPART(dw, getdate())), getdate()) as date) [Week1 End]

select cast(DATEADD(dd, -8-(DATEPART(dw, getdate())-2), getdate()) as date) [Week2 start]

select cast(DATEADD(dd, -14-(DATEPART(dw, getdate())-2), getdate()) as date) [Week2 END]
```

which showing wrong output, can some help me in this, by pointing out where I am going wrong , or an alternative to getting the last 6-week start and end dates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try storing the current week start / end in variables and then use `DATEADD` to calculate the previous weeks:

```
declare @weekStart date = cast(DATEADD(dd, -(DATEPART(dw, getdate())-1), getdate()) as date)
declare @weekEnd date = cast(DATEADD(dd, 7-(DATEPART(dw, getdate())), getdate()) as date)

select @weekStart, @weekEnd
union all
select DATEADD(dd, -7, @weekStart), DATEADD(dd, -7, @weekEnd)
union all
select DATEADD(dd, -7 * 2, @weekStart), DATEADD(dd, -7  * 2, @weekEnd)
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=8132c3489a9fc51d5d1e8173bd3efa7c)

Answer (score 1):

Also you can solve this task with recursive CTE:

```
WITH cte

AS
(
     SELECT cast(DATEADD(dd, -(DATEPART(dw, getdate())-1), getdate()) as date) [Week1 start], cast(DATEADD(dd, 7-(DATEPART(dw, getdate())), getdate()) as date) [Week1 End]

     UNION ALL  
      SELECT cast(DATEADD(dd, -7-(DATEPART(dw, [Week1 start])-1), [Week1 start]) as date) [Week1 start], cast(DATEADD(dd, -1-(DATEPART(dw, [Week1 End])-1), [Week1 End]) as date) [Week1 End]

     FROM cte
     WHERE [Week1 start]>'2021-01-10'
)
     SELECT * FROM cte
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
select cast(DATEADD(dd, -(DATEPART(dw, getdate())-1), getdate()) as date) [Week1 start]
select cast(DATEADD(dd, 7-(DATEPART(dw, getdate())), getdate()) as date) [Week1 End]
select cast(DATEADD(dd, -8-(DATEPART(dw, getdate())-2), getdate()) as date) [Week2 start]
select cast(DATEADD(dd, -(DATEPART(dw, getdate())), getdate()) as date) [Week2 END]
select cast(DATEADD(dd, -15-(DATEPART(dw, getdate())-2), getdate()) as date) [Week3 start]
select cast(DATEADD(dd, -7-(DATEPART(dw, getdate())), getdate()) as date) [Week3 END]
```